# Unable to get name of table from DataTableReader object

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have created a DataSet object from an XML file.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    XmlTextReader xmltext = new XmlTextReader(sr);
    ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(xmltext);
}
```

Then I create a DataTableReader object and start to loop through each table and each row.

```
using (DataTableReader dtr = ds.CreateDataReader())
{
    while (dtr.NextResult())  // foreach table
    {
        // would like to access table name here

        while (dtr.Read())   // foreach row
        {
             ....
```

My problem is that I would like access the name of each table in the DataTableReader, but there doesn't seem to be a property available for me to use.

If I inspect the DataTableReader object I see the table name is stored in a property called "CurrentDataTable", but this is a non-public member and I cannot access it.

I have also tried using the 'GetSchemaTable' function on the DataTableReader which returns a DataTable object.  This seemed promising at first, but the 'TableName' property of the DataTable object has a value of "SchemaTable" which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to find a work around.  There are some other StackOverflow answers I found which suggested using reflection to access the non-public member.

This code allowed me to access the string I was seeking.

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = dtr.GetType()
     .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
     .Single(x => x.Name == "CurrentDataTable");

pInfo.GetValue(dtr, null).ToString();
```

While this is technically working it feels like a very ham-fisted way to accomplish something that seems so trivial.

Surely there is a better way?